# Does Saturn have a weak spot?

Tags: borderlands-2

I understand that Saturn, being an armoured enemy, is vulnerable to corrosive attacks. However, he has a stunning amount of health and the damage he is able to kill me in one hit. I plan to level up once again before I attack him but I would like to know his weak spot so as to make him easier to kill.

I have attempted to hit the weak spot of the other bots. such as its the wires in between his armour but no avail.

**Why is this so? Is it because I am hitting the wrong spot? If so, where is his weak spot?**

Comment: Do you only want to know about Saturn's weak spot or would you also like answers about general strategies on how to beat Saturn?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Saturn's weak spot is on its back side. You will need to get around behind him to hit it. For Zer0, Gaige, or Axton characters, this can be easy, using the holo-decoy, Deathtrap, or the Sabre Turret to lure him into facing away from you. For the other characters, it can be more challenging; you may need to run in through his legs, get past him, and turn around to shoot at his back before he can maneuver.

Comment: Is it possible to slag him

Comment: @DavidToh that should probably be asked as a separate question, possibly expanded out into a "Which bosses can be slagged, and which can't?", though we might already have something; search around a bit first.

Comment: According to a "famous" youtuber, Saturn has no crit spot: https://youtu.be/5mXzdrGtutU Can you proof, he has one?

Answer (score 1):

Saturn has no crit spot. You can see this for yourself with zero's b0re skill, which highlights crit spots while you're in deception. I've personally shot him all over too. There's no crit spot on his back.